# AutoLayout doesn't work fine

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying create an app compatible with iPhone 4s and 5 but when I run in iphone 4S my screen appears wrong...

Look at the images
[image: I need that the app appears like this]

[image: The app appears like this]

[image: facebook button]

[image: foursquare button]

Comment: What are your autoresizing settings for the facebook button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't explicitly stating the relationship between the login button, and the other buttons, so the constraint is just leaving it where it is, whereas the other buttons do have constraints, and are being adjusted accordingly. Try adding a constraint to the login button

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! I did add a constraint in foursquare button